# Chess960 tips and strategies

Tags: chess-variants, chess960

I have recently stared to play chess variants, and I want become better at them. Are there any strategies for chess960 given that the piece placement is random each time?

Comment: There's this? https://lichess.org/study/UQTwIHXt I got it from here https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/starting-positions-in-chess960-where-black-is-definitely-worse i asked about it here https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33812/patterns-in-chess960-positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have learned in classical chess but opening variations also applies in Chess960 : respective values of the pieces, king safety, development, center, activity, concrete calculations, open lines, pawn structure, endgame theory, initiative, etc.

All those concepts are essential to Chess960's strategy. This explains why the best Chess960 players are the best chess players: they don't need specific training or strategy to adapt to the game, as they would if they wanted to try bughouse or loser chess or 4-players chess.

Comment: What do you say to this? https://lichess.org/study/UQTwIHXt I got it from here https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/starting-positions-in-chess960-where-black-is-definitely-worse