# Chess960 Swiss tournament tips

Tags: chess960, swiss-pairing

Does anyone have recommendations for a Chess960 Swiss tournament, where each round is a new position?

A possible problem is that [some of the start positions are quite advantageous for White](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/), so it may be unfair to players if they get such a position as Black .

Also it is possible in Swiss for people to get an excess of 2 more Black than White which is  also more of a disadvantage in Chess960 than in regular chess.

In the world championship they play double round robin with each player playing the same position as white and black, so this issue doesn't arise.

E.g. does anyone exclude certain possible start positions that are too unbalanced, or use some tweaks to the pairing algorithm?

I couldn't find any FIDE advice on Chess960 Swiss.